# Jumping caret at begining

Tags: angular, typescript

In HTML:

```
<div id="b" *ngFor="let key of metadataKeys; let i = index">
    <span> {{key}} -></span>
    <span id="a" #metaValue contentEditable="" [innerHTML]="this.header.metaDataJson[key]"
        (keyup)="metaDataChange(metaValue, i)"></span> 
</div>
```

In ts file I try set cursor position:

```
metaDataChange(element, index) {
    this.header.metaDataJson[this.metadataKeys[index]] = element.innerHTML;
    let caretCurPos = element.innerHTML.length;
    let span = document.getElementById('a');
    let range = document.createRange();
    let node = document.getElementById("b"); 
    range.setStart(node.childNodes[0], 1); 
    range.setStart(span, 1); 
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    span.focus(); 
}
```

Cursor jumps at the begining in this line when new value is set.

```
this.header.metaDataJson[this.metadataKeys[index]] = element.innerHTML;
```

How to avoid jumping caret? Is possible using some alternative to contentEditable? And I don't want use input.